# Why am I getting an error when trying to plot this graph?

Tags: labview

Everything else works except when I try to plot this graph.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is because the type of data expected by the **Waveform Graph** is not what you give it.
You may want to use **Waveform Chart**. Have a look at  [Type of Graphs and Charts](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvconcepts/types_of_graphs_and_charts/). A graph expects a data-set (or multiple data points) as an array or waveform, while a chart expects a data-point.

Answer (score 1):

You must connect array of numbers to Waveform Graph.
Just add a shift register with empty array on initialization and build new array by adding a new value on any iteration.